# 同一目的のマクロの処理を複数のファイルに対して一括でキューに追加して行うことは可能でしょうか？

Tags: emeditor

EmEditor Professionalでお世話になっております。

大量のWAVファイルをキューに追加してMP3にコンバートするみたいなことをマクロでもやりたいのです。

○○に変換マクロを大量の文書システムに適応するときに、いちいち1個ずつ開いて終わったら手動で保存をするのではなく、キューに追加したファイルは全部処理して保存までしてくれる方法です。
適応するマクロは同一のもので、目的も同一の場合です。
そのときに
上書きではなく、「マクロ実行済み」などとファイル名に追加して別に指定フォルダに保存してくれるとありがたいです。

必要な理由としては使うときに一瞬で処理できるようなものではなく、1ファイル当たり数十分かかる処理のためです。
EmEditor Professionalでは動作しましたが他のテキストエディタでは動作しないか動作しても数十時間かかりました。
このためコンバートソフトのように使いたいのです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

`ファイル` メニューの `高度に開く` を選択して、マクロを指定し、複数のファイルを選択して開けば、ファイルを開いてマクロを実行という動作を、指定したファイルの数だけ繰り返し行うようになります。マクロには、ファイルを編集して保存する内容を記述しておきます。

[image: EmEditor 高度に開く]

Comment: ご回答頂き、ありがとうございます。
これは便利な機能です!
開いた途端に全部にマクロが実行されてました。
これだと1万ファイルとかでも一瞬の手間で済みます。